# Writing and reading from file descriptor 3 and /proc

Tags: bash, shell, file-descriptors, deleted-files

When I run the following command:

```
exec 3<<< "TEST"
```

I can see the following appear in `/proc` (note last line regarding FD3 reading deleted):

```
# ls -al /proc/$$/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 root root  0 Jan 18 21:09 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root  0 Jan 18 21:09 ..
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 28 16:22 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 28 16:22 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 18 21:09 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 28 16:22 255 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jan 28 20:42 3 -> /tmp/sh-thd-1123912022914878506 (deleted)
```

And I can read the contents of FD 3 once but no more after:

```
# cat 0<&3
TEST
# cat 0<&3
# cat 0<&3
```

My question is if in `/proc/$$/fd/3` it was reading as "deleted" already, what's the theory behind why I could still read its contents?

Comment: In general, while original files ( in this case temp file that stores here-string ) can be deleted, if it was opened in `/proc`, then it's technically loaded into kernel memory. See this for example: https://www.linux.com/news/bring-back-deleted-files-lsof

Comment: @Serg That's not quite true: the file is still stored wherever it was stored. It isn't in kernel memory, except for any part that's cached.

Comment: @Gilles  Technically, if I understand correctly, data is stored where it was on disk, but file name is unlinked and filesystem makes that space available for overwriting. Since symlinks break when the file to which they point ( and  `/proc/$$/fd/3` ) , the data written to file descriptor 3  has to be cached, and technically they are loaded into memory. But correct me if I'm wrong. It probably would be better if you posted an actual answer, because discussion in comments are limited

Answer (score 3):

You can still read from the file descriptor. The problem is that you are using "dup2" system call to make a second reference to a file descriptor, and a file descriptor has a position. After your first cat the position is at the end of the data. You can read the data a bit at a time (here I use `read` as an example to read a line at a time, normally you would use read -r), and I am using perl as an easy way to rewind the position to the start of the file.

```
 $ exec 3<<<'This is some text
 > and some more
 > that is all folks'
 $ read <&3 ; echo "$REPLY"
 This is some text
 $ read <&3 ; echo "$REPLY"
 and some more
 $ perl -e 'sysseek(stdin,0,0);' <&3
 $ read <&3 ; echo "$REPLY"
 This is some text
```

Comment: cat resets file descriptors to the beginning before reading.

Comment: @Ajax Not for any sane version of cat! If there was such a seek how do you explain the OP's behaviour where they only get `TEST` output once?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838322/bash-read-write-file-descriptors-seek-to-start-of-file/47091972#47091972

If you are accessing the file via `/proc/self/fd/#` you can use cat to push the file descriptor to the end to keep appending to the file.

Comment: errrr.... perhaps I misunderstood the linked answer.  It's the `>>` causing append...

Answer (score 1):

A file is “deleted” when there is no more directory entry pointing to that file. It's possible for a file to be deleted in this sense, but to still exist on the disk. The [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) for the file, as well as the file's content, are not deleted until the file is closed.

When a file has no directory entry, there's no way to open it directly. However, it's still possible to duplicate existing descriptors to that file, which is what redirection on `/proc/PID/fd/FD` does.

If the system crashes with the file still open but deleted, then the data will be deleted later: either on the next boot when the journal is replayed, or by [fsck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck) when it detects a file with a [link count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed that file descriptor, so you haven't released its resources.  You have, however, read everything that is ever going to be available on that file descriptor.  Future reads will just immediate get an EOF, but the file descriptor hasn't been closed so it still exists.

Comment: you can still reset the file and use it again. Many examples in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47091972/1218010 but the linked one has a copy-paste test you can use to see how to easily use/reuse a file descriptor to a deleted file.